# How to use gsem when the independent variables are binary?

Tags: logistic, stata, structural-equation-modeling, probit

According to [this website](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/generalized-sem/), "Binary—probit, logit, complementary log-log". But does the "binary" here mean independent variable or the latent variable (that is determined by the independent variable)?

I am esp. unsure since probit and logit are used to model binary dependent variables. So I find it strange that when input variables are binary, Bernoulli logit is used, as done [here in the first figure](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/generalized-sem/). Also I wonder how can we know that "MathApt" has a Bernoulli distribution? (If I understand the [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/semgsemfamily-and-linkoptions.pdf) correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli/binomial indicates that the outcome is binary, but you could use different link functions, like probit or logit. The latent/unobserbed variables (math aptitude and school quality) are continuous.

The probit or logit choice rarely matters in practice in that the marginal effects will be similar. The coefficients, of course, will be quite different.

Comment: Just to make sure: by "outcome", do you mean the measured variables? (i.e. whether q1 was answered correctly in the example I mentioned in the question?) 

Also when should I use Bernoulli and when should I use binomial? I do not think it is possible to have binomial distribution for binary, which only has 0 and 1.

Comment: Outcome is pass/fail as measured on the test. Binomial without specifying the number of trials defaults to Bernoulli, which is binomial with one trial.

Comment: OK so if I specified the family as binomial for binary outcomes, the program would just interpret it as bernoulli?

Comment: If you wrote family(binomial), then yes. The general syntax is family(binomial k) or family(binomial num_trials_var). To get Bernoulli, you can set k to 1 or have a variable that is all ones. For code readability reasons, however, family(bernoulli) seems best to me.